add noise in pydub on different noise level
I am trying to add noise to an audio, but I want the added noise to be scaled based on the probability of each segment in the audio. For each segment, if probability = 1, the noise will be the highest, and if probability = 0, no noise will be added. I am doing the following but I don't think it is actually working, I see no change in noise level.
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import ratio_to_db
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise
from pydub.silence import detect_silence
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise

audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path, format="wav")
noise = WhiteNoise().to_audio_segment(duration=500)
adjusted_noise = noise.apply_gain(ratio_to_db(0.001))
audio = audio[:1000] + adjusted_noise + audio[1500:]

output_path = 'masked.wav'
audio.export(output_path, format="wav")


You're not showing your probability variable, and the 0.001 ratio is way too small.

what is the probability variable? what should be good value instead of 0.001

You said "based on the probability of each segment". Anyway, the "ratio" is the relationship between the original amplitude (volume) and the raised amplitude (volume). For instance, a ratio of 2 (which is about +6 in dB) will double the amplitude/volumen of the noise.

yes i have tried with different ratio. think of the probability as anything between 0 and 1. so if there are 5 segments with probabilities 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.9,0.1 i want the fourth segment to have the peak noise and the rest lowered according to their probability

can you provide a working code that can increase/decrease the volume based on a given parameter?

I still don't get where the "probability" comes from, but I'll give it a try. Check my answer.

Let's see if I can help you.
First attempt (joining)
This first code is almost the same as yours, but using a variable for establishing the volume of the noise. (The value of noiseVolume would be your "probability".) But I don't think this is what you're really looking for, as it just slices the audio in two and joins the noise in the "middle".
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import ratio_to_db
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise

# Relative volume of the noise (0: no noise; 1: maximum noise)
noiseVolume = 0.5

# Read the audio file (which should contain at least 500 mseconds)
audio_path = "441 Hz - 44100 Hz - 16 bit.wav"
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path, format="wav")

# Generate 500 mseconds of white noise
noise = WhiteNoise().to_audio_segment(duration=500)

# Change the volume of the noise
adjusted_noise = noise.apply_gain(ratio_to_db(noiseVolume))

# Create a new audio: 500 msecs of audio + 500 msecs of noise + remaining audio
audio = audio[:500] + adjusted_noise + audio[500:]

# Save it
output_path = 'masked.wav'
audio.export(output_path, format="wav")

Take a (zoomed) look at the first joining point, where the first "half" of the original audio (in this case, a pure sine wave) leads to the noise.


Second attempt (mixing)
This second code creates a longer noise (as long as the original audio) and mixes the audio with the noise (adding their sound waves).
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import ratio_to_db
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise

# Relative volume of the noise (0: no noise; 1: pure noise)
noiseVolume = 0.5

# Read the audio file (of any length)
audio_path = "441 Hz - 44100 Hz - 16 bit.wav"
audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_path, format="wav")

# Generate white noise of the same duration as the audio
noise = WhiteNoise().to_audio_segment(duration=len(audio))

# Change the volume of the noise.
adjusted_noise = noise.apply_gain(ratio_to_db(noiseVolume))

# Mix the original audio with the noise
audio = audio.overlay(adjusted_noise)

# Save it
output_path = 'masked.wav'
audio.export(output_path, format="wav")

The result will look like this (for a noiseVolume == 0.2):

Or like this (for a noiseVolume == 0.5):

Please note that I'm not reducing the volume of the original audio, and it may "clip" when added to the noise. You could reduce the volume of the original audio (as much as you raise the volume of the noise). Also note that I'm talking about "volume" but the correct word is "amplitude". (The "volume" is a perceived magnitude which directly depends on the physical "amplitude" but also on other factors.)

thanks, i will try to run it and then get back to you. overlay is what i wanted, but for specific durations wihtin the audio, say from audio[300:900]

You welcome. You can use the form audio.overlay (adjusted_noise, position=300) with a noise whose duration was 600 (900-300).
